# Find the value of : $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{...+\sqrt{2}}}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, nested-radicals

This is a nice limit
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\underbrace{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{...+\sqrt{2}}}}}_{n\text{ times}}$$
and it is solved with well-known trigonometry formulas. The result is 2. The question is: can be, this limit, solved in other ways?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $x_0=\sqrt 2$ and $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+x_n}$, then you can prove by induction that $x_{n}<2$ and $x_n$ is increasing. So a limit must exist.

But any limit must be a positive $x$ satisfying $x = \sqrt{2+x}$. So $x=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as there is no $n$ in your expression, having $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ doesn't really make sense. I would just express it as $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{...+\sqrt{2}}}}$

Just suppose there is some number $A$ such that $A = \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{...+\sqrt{2}}}}$. then we can square and subtract two from both sides and get $A^2 -2 = \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{...+\sqrt{2}}}}$. But the right-hand side is the same in both of these, so we have $A^2 - 2 = A$. Solve this quadratic for $A$ and we see that in fact $A = 2$

Comment: But you need to prove that such a limit exists. For example, $1,3,9,\dots$ would have limit $0$, since any limit must have $3A=A$, that means the limit must be $0$. If it exists. :)

Comment: The expression $n$ is the number of terms in the square root. There is no infinite expression of that form that "terminates."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews However, mapierce271 is right in saying there is no $n$ in the expression, thus the question is not asked correctly. Usually, there is at list a line to tell what you write. Without that, there could be $n^2$ square roots, or $n\  \mathrm{mod} \ 10$, or whatever.

Comment: The expression is meaningless if it implies an infinite number of terms. It is true, OP didn't say what he meant, but this answer implies it makes sense to write $A = \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{...+\sqrt{2}}}}$ as if there were such an expression with infinite number of terms. The terminating $\sqrt{2}$ means the definition doesn't makes sense for infinite terms. @Jean-ClaudeArbaut

Comment: The formula now has a notation indicating that there are $n$ nested square roots. Hopefully that resolves the "number of terms" concern.

Answer (score 0):

If the limit exists, the recursive function is very simply:
$$n=\sqrt{2+n}$$

Hence:

$$n^2-n-2=0 \\ (n-2)(n+1)=0 \\n=2$$

$n$ is indeed $2$.

Comment: That assumes a limit exists, of course...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I assume the OP is given that the limit exists.